# UTF-32 decoding in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, utf-32

I have UTF-32 data, an array buffer. I need to convert it into an ECMAScript string.

I've been told that I can just use TextDecoder with UTF-8, and it is supposed to "just work," I highly doubted the person who had told me this, but it worked anyways.

Except... the output text is riddled with null characters (3 per character), due to reading the null byte padding as a null character, instead of reading the whole four bytes as one character.
ex:

`\x70\x00\x00\x00`

becomes

`P` UTF-32; null padding is read as one character

`P\0\0\0` UTF-8; separated

According to the whatwg encoding spec, UTF-32 is not defined as an encoding label to be used, but instead, only UTF-8, and UTF-16, not UTF-32, does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve proper UTF-32 decoding, within a browser?

To be clear, I care about modern browsers, so I am excluding IE, Amaya, Android Webview, and Netscape Navigator, etc.

Comment: Are the input bytes little-endian UTF-32, or `Uint32Array` (platform-dependent) endianness?

Comment: This library supports converting from utf-32: https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite. It works in browser as well.

Comment: worst case scenario, u see what the null values look like, so you can make a render function urself

Comment: for example: `function renderData(da){return(da.split(\`\\0\`).join(\`\`))}`

Comment: @Ry- Now, as for the endianness of the data, I'm confident that it is little-endian. Didn't the example given show the endian of the data? If it helps to know, it's a Wasm data section, so I believe that it would not be platform dependant, as the data is hardcoded into it, but I'm not sure how browsers handle that.

Comment: @JadenGarcia: The example showed that it couldn’t be big-endian, but it could have been little-endian because the example was produced on a little-endian platform. That’s why I wanted to make sure. Knowing it’s hardcoded answers that, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding it as UTF-8 is definitely wrong! As you found out. In addition to the NUL thing, it will fail to decode characters outside of ASCII entirely.

You can read the codepoints one by one with a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getInt32) to decode:

```js
const utf32Decode = bytes => {
  const view = new DataView(bytes.buffer, bytes.byteOffset, bytes.byteLength);
  let result = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += 4) {
    result += String.fromCodePoint(view.getInt32(i, true));
  }
  
  return result;
};

const result = utf32Decode(new Uint8Array([0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Invalid UTF-32 will throw an error, thanks to `getInt32` (invalid lengths) and [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) (invalid codepoints).

Comment: Yes, the null characters are not the major problem, I could easily just filter them at worst, what I feared was that some characters that are too large would be not be decoded properly at all. I was thinking about just rewriting it to output ASCII instead of UTF-32, but I may need some larger code points later, and leaving it could be helpful.

I'll test this right now.

Comment: @JadenGarcia: If you’re in control of the source, how about making it output UTF-8? It’s pretty much *the* standard encoding. `TextDecoder` will be correct at that point :)

Comment: Well, yes, I am in control of the source, but UTF-8 is quite a hard encoding to actually operate on when programming. Iteration over the data wouldn't be as straightforward as just accessing fixed-width 32-bit integers. And I would lose out on random access.

Comment: Wait, doesn't `String.fromCodePoint` only allow UTF-16 code points? Thus any code point past 0xfff should throw an error, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @JadenGarcia: That’s `String.fromCharCode`.

Comment: Right right, I've been using `fromCodePoint` and `codePointAt` for so long that I had forgotten that the alternative had existed.

Comment: Literally dropped in the function as a replacement for the faulty `TextDecoder`, worked flawlessly. Thank you. Although, if I might ask, couldn't I just use a `Uint32Array`, as opposed to the `DataView`?

Comment: @JadenGarcia: `Uint32Array` technically has platform-dependent endianness.

Comment: I see, annoying, but worth noting, thank you once again.

Comment: @sld: No, it doesn’t. Try anything outside of ASCII, or note the several NUL characters that made it into the string.

Answer (score -1):

Use this library: https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite. It works in-browser using browserify or webpack (though it's pretty big).

Example:

```js
const iconv = require("iconv-lite")

const yourBuffer = // however you're getting your buffer

const str = iconv.decode(yourBuffer, "utf32");
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but it seems to target Node.js, with the browser package being "~180kb" at the largest. Yeah, I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel, that's a bonus, and I'm sure that it could be stripped down, but I would definitely have to review the source before I put it to use, and that would be quite a lot to review.

Comment: @JadenGarcia I mostly just posted it in case someone else finds this question in the future. It's one of the few packages I found that handles utf32.